# MySql.Data not listed under references in visual studio 2008

Tags: .net, connector, mysql.data

It was working well when 6.2.2 installed. Then i uninstalled it and install the newest version(6.3.5)
but now, MySql.Data do not displaying under Add Reference window.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET tab of that dialog only lists .NET framework assemblies.  Sometimes some additional ones when an installer messes with the registry entries, that's not common.  You'll have to use the Browse tab and navigate to the assembly in its install directory.

Comment: I have added manually from C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.3.5\Assemblies\v2.0 and works!..Thanks